# Getting server settings from within Symfony console

Tags: php, symfony, server, console

How can I access the `$_SERVER` settings from within the Symfony console?
They don't seem to be recognised...

Comment: What sort of server settings do you expect to be able to get from the console?  From the manual: $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it direct. The Symfony HttpFoundation component replaces these default PHP global variables and functions by an object-oriented layer.
Look at this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html 
Here is described, how you can get the desired data

Comment: Are you talking about the Symfony request object?  If so, what sort of request do you expect to get in a command console?